# MissingReferenceException in AudioSource on DontDestroyOnLoad GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was getting Missing Reference Exception within my Audio Source when I change my game scene and again move back to the same scene.

Before I change the main menu scene, it is working fine but after changing and moving back to the main menu scene, it is started showing this exception.

[image]

Here is the code I have written for AudioManager:

```
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
 static AudioManager instance;
 //
 [SerializeField] AudioClip buttonClickClip;
 [SerializeField] AudioSource myAudioSource;

 private void Awake()
 {
     instance = this;
 }

 public static AudioManager Instance
 {
     get
     {
         return instance;
     }
 }

 public void PlayButtonClickSound()
 {
     if (GameManager.Instance.IsEnableSounds)
         myAudioSource.PlayOneShot(buttonClickClip);
 }

}
```

Here is the code that I wrote for DontDestroyOnLoad purpose:

```
public class DontDetroyOnLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
 private static bool created = false;

 void Awake()
 {
     if (!created)
     {
         DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
         created = true;
     }
     else
         Destroy(this.gameObject);
 }

}
```

Now please give me some suggestion to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the AudioManager that you are destroying in the script that is trying to play the sound.

Think of it this way. You have

AudioManager A - DontDestroyOnLoad

AudioManager B - That gets destroyed cause A exists

In your scripts you are referencing AudioManager A when you first start up. Then when you leave the Scene and return you are now referencing AudioManager B, which got destroyed because A exists. All you need to do is always reference AudioManager A, not B.

Comment: I think you are in the right direction... but how to do this?

Comment: What object is your `MainMenuPanelController.cs` attached to? If you are using a public or SerializedField and dragging in your AudioManager directly then that is why you are receiving a null ref. You will want to use FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>() AFTER AudioManager B is destroyed or consider using the Singleton Pattern you have already established via AudioManager.Instance.

Comment: I can't able to place anything in the main menu controller script because other scenes also using the same sounds so they can't able to find an audio source.

Comment: ANSWER: Okay I find the solution by creating different audio sources in different scenes and access them in don't destroy on load script. - Actual problem reason you found so I am marking your answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the answer from @jfish. That clearly describes the situation.

Here let me elaborate mine, on the example of using [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

```
[SerializeField] AudioSource audioSource;
void Awake()
{
    GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("music");

    if (objs.Length > 1)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);

        //Here, get the previous audioSource from previous game object
        audioSource = objs[0].GetComponent<AudioSource>(); 
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

On first load, it gets from Editor.

Subsequently, it gets from previous game object.